# Give process permissions programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to run a jar in C# by running this code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(pathForjre+"java.exe", "-jar "+jar+" "+argsforjar);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow  = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = processInfo;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

string out = "";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
       out += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
proc.Close();
return out;
```

When the jar runs I get an access denied exception with the path the jar is trying to write the log file to. I can manually run the jar from the command line and the log file writes no problem. How do I give the process permission to do things like write a file?

Comment: How are you starting/running the C# code?

Comment: Are you by any chance missing asp.net tag from the post?

Comment: Check working directory, maybe you're trying to write to different locations

Comment: I hard coded the directory in the jar to test if that was the problem and it ran fine from the command line.

Comment: Can you please describe the working directory? In what context does the program is running? With context I mean is it an administrator or other kind of user.

Comment: The working directory is on a server. I am not the administrator of the directory (I as the user have permissions to read and write). However, I created a .bat file and called that from my C# and the .bat called the jar and the jar could write to working directory on the server just fine. The only time it won't write is when the jar is called directly by the C# program.

Comment: I also created a separate program in C# to see if a stand alone C# program had permissions to write to the directory and it could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the working directory of the process resolved the issue.

```
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET apps by default don't impersonate the identity of the user that is hitting the site.  Typically then run as the local Network Service account unless you specifically have the process run under a different identity (you can determine the identity it's using by looking at [`Environment.UserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx)).

You can either set up the site (or use impersonation) to run under an identity that has permission to write to that location, or give write permision to the account that it's currently using.